# Spring @PropertyValue annotation is not working in Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have `email.properties` file under `/src/main/resources/` and also in `/src/test/resources/` folder.

I am trying to read the properties using `@PropertyValue` annotation.
I have registered the Bean in my `SpringConfig.java` file.

Inside SpringConfig.java :

```
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Inside EmailConfig.java :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/src/main/resources/email.properties")

public class EmailConfig {


    @Value("${smtp_userName}")
    private String smtp_userName;

    @Value("${forgotPasswordTemplate}")
    private String forgotPasswordTemplate;

    @Value("${forgotPasswordSubject}")
    private String forgotPasswordSubject;

    // corresponding getter, setters and constructors ()
}
```

I wrote a unit test for the above piece which is not working!

Inside my EmailConfigTest.java :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.time.dal.config.EmailConfig;

public class EmailConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    EmailConfig emailConfig;

    @Value("${smtp_userName}")
    private String smtp_userName;

    @Value("${forgotPasswordTemplate}")
    private String forgotPasswordTemplate;

    @Value("${forgotPasswordSubject}")
    private String forgotPasswordSubject;

    @Test
    public void testEmailConfig(){


        System.out.println("SMTP User Name is  "+smtp_userName);
        Assert.assertNotNull(smtp_userName);
}
```

Here's my error :

> SMTP User Name is  null FAILED: testEmailConfig
>   java.lang.AssertionError: expected object to not be null  at
>   com.time.dal.utils.EmailConfigTest.testEmailConfig(EmailConfigTest.java:31)

Comment: Please add the content of email.properties.

Comment: First please annotate the test class with SpringJunitRunner and set the context configuration if you are using xml based configuration

Comment: There is no `/src/main/resources` as that is the root of the class path... Remove the `//src/main/resources/` part from the `@PropertySource` annotation. next to that you have only some annotations on fields in your test but no `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4Runner.class)` so it is a plain unit test and basically your annotations do nothing due to this.

Comment: How to use TestNG instead of SpringJUnitRunner?